# Does Intel IPP image resize function care about position of alpha value?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I'm using IPP to resize image efficiently, but the really curious part of IPP is 'Does IPP image resize function care about alpha value position?'

There's really lot of pixel type of image, but there's well-used two pixel type: 'ARGB, RGBA'. and the `ippiResizeNearest_8u_C4R` function resize **four-channel-image** according to [Intel IPP function naming documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/503703).

And as you can see at documentation, we can distinguish function caring position of alpha channel like: `A`, `A0`. but `ippiResizeNearest_8u_C4R` function doesn't have any of alpha channel descriptor. so I can't even expect which color-order IPP resizes.

so my question is: Do Intel IPP image resize function **care** about position of alpha value? if not, what's the default pixel type for `ippiResizeNearest_8u_C4R` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no IPP expert but a quick read in the documentation seems to confirm what I believe to be correct. Anything else wouldn't make sense to me.

Resizing a multi channel image is usually done for each channel separately because interpolation between channels just doesn't make sense (given that we are talking about 2d images). It would completely mess up colours and transparencies.

And if we do it for every channel separately, IPP should not care about how you call your channels. It will resize ARGB the same way as RGBA. It will not change the channel order so if you put ARGB in you'll get a resized ARGB out. In case of resizing it does not matter what you store in those 4 channels.

Just try it out. Create a test image with different values in each channel. The resized image should still have those values.